# How to expand panels in ngb-accordion while automatically updating ngFor data structure

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngx-charts

I am using an ngFor loop to display dynamically updated data with ngb-accordion. I have all of the accordion panels active when the page is first displayed; however, when the data structure is automatically updated the panels collapse.  I would like for them to remain open and display the refreshed data.  The dashboardDataMulti is the variable that is being altered within the component.  I am not sure what is causing the panels to collapse, but I can say for sure it is happening when the dashboardDataMulti variable is being updated.

Update: I was able to reproduce the error without ngx-charts.  The problem appears to by an issue with ng-bootstrap or Angular in which dynamic data is repopulated within the accordion (code edited for brevity).

HTML code:

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of dashboardDataMulti; index as i">
            <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-{{i}}" type="light">
                <ngb-panel  title="{{data.name}}">
                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                    </ng-template>
                </ngb-panel>
            </ngb-accordion>
        </div>
```

Component timer:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.generateDashboardData();
      // change the data periodically
      this.dataInterval = setInterval(() => this.generateDashboardData(), 10 * 600);
}, 1000);
```

Added plunker to mimic the problem I'm having.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YJGXuoVGC9MeTJfpmPRb

As you can see the originalData displays with all accordions expanded as I would like; however, when the originalData array is dynamically updated all of the accordions collapse.  How can I update this data structure and keep the panels open for viewing?

Answer (score 2):

The `<ngb-panel>` needed an id tag.  I updated the code with the following to achieve the desired results.

```
    <ngb-panel  title="{{data.name}}" id="ngb-panel-{{i}}">
```

A Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rg1qPpe3YKeStBCaOVMb